# How to customize a new google signin button in angular?

Tags: angular, google-oauth, google-signin, angular-ui

Using of updated plugin for angular 13, 14 @abacritt/angularx-social-login

how do i customized this google sign in button to local css.

> 'asl-google-signin-button type='standard' size='large' shape='circle' asl-google-signin-button'